# Installer Crashed!!! Help needed!

Tags: installation

I am new to ubuntu. So i was trying it out before i get accustomed to it. Today While installing Ubuntu 10.10 from the try now desktop, the installer has been crashing in the middle of installation. Asking this Question, through the Try now desktop.

Comment: Welcome to AU!  As Roland mentioned, it would be a good idea to use a version that is going to be supported for longer, such as 11.10.    Beyond that, you will need to include more details about what is going wrong for us to help.  What error message did it display?  What step was it on when it crashed? etc.

Comment: I rebooted my PC and tried the installation again. So the actual problem lies with the disk. it is said to be damaged.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The disk image can be damaged generally in two ways:

1. If the downloaded `.iso` file is corrupted during the download process.  To check for this, find the MD5 checksum of your image and check it against the correct value (available on the download page).
2. If burning the image to a physical CD (or DVD) had a problem.

If the MD5 checksum checks out, try re-burning your disc at a lower speed.

Comment: That was very helpful but after doing a lot of searches, i know that i have to download a new .iso . and make a new CD. As this CD was a year old. And i deleted the iso a long time ago.

Answer (score 0):

Just run the installer again. By the way you should try installing a newer version of Ubuntu than 10.10, such as 11.10 or 11.04, or even wait till 12.04 comes out and try that.

10.10 is not a long term support release and won't be around for too long.

Comment: I am having the 11.10 server edition. There is a problem in installing ubuntu-desktop, and connecting to thye internet in it.

Comment: And i ran the installer. But it crashed again.